# jQuery: Stop a function and call it again

Tags: jquery

I am currently developing an small webapp for an iPad.
now I'm using [touchslider](http://touchslider.com). For a small "Zoom Function" I'm using a toggle function, to show and hide some divs. now i would like to stop the touchslider, so that the user can't swipe tru the slides. 
but just until the user toggled the #zoom1 -button, at this point the slider should be available again.
i tried with unbind, stop and start the slider but it seems i am on the wrong way...

```
$(".touchslider15").touchSlider({
container: this,
duration: 350, 
delay: 3000, 
margin: 0,
mouseTouch: true,
autoplay: false, 
viewport: ".touchslider-viewport15"}); 

$("#zoom1").toggle(function(){
$('#header').hide();
$(".touchslider15").unbind('touchSlider', touchSlider);
},function(){ 
    $('#header').show();
});
```

Comment: That version of `toggle()` is deprecated, and `touchslider` does not seem to be an event you can just unbind! You'll have to look at the plugin and see if it has a method for destroying the instance!

Answer (score 1):

Look's like it's something like this:

```
var state=true;

$(".touchslider15").touchSlider({
    container: this,
    duration: 350, 
    delay: 3000, 
    margin: 0,
    mouseTouch: true,
    autoplay: false, 
    viewport: ".touchslider-viewport15"
}); 

$("#zoom1").on('click', function() {
    $(".touchslider15").data("touchslider")[state?'stop':'start']();
    $("#header").toggle(!state);
    state=!state;
});
```

**Edit**: not sure it will work, but you could try:

```
$("#zoom1").on('click', function() {
    if (state) {
        var elem = $(".touchslider15").clone(false);
        $(".touchslider15").replaceWith(elem);
    }else{
        $(".touchslider15").touchSlider({
            container: this,
            duration: 350, 
            delay: 3000, 
            margin: 0,
            mouseTouch: true,
            autoplay: false, 
            viewport: ".touchslider-viewport15"
        }); 
    }
    $("#header").toggle(!state);
    state=!state;
});
```

Comment: @Cycle99 - You're welcome, looked in the plugin code, and there does'nt seem to be any other methods for stopping the slider. If it works, please accept the answer ?

Comment: I've tried it, and it does'nt seem to stop the manual sliding, and there does'nt seem to be any way to that at all ?

Comment: i was too fast with my answer, sorry adeno. your method just works with auto slides, not with manually swipe true the slides. it stops and starts auto slides.

Comment: there's also no manual on the plugins website, i checked it at least four times

Comment: is there a way, to kill the code and render it again? i know, it seems like a killermethod, but if it works?

Comment: Try `$('.touchslider-viewport15').unbind('touchstart')` just for fun ?

Comment: Added a possible solution, cloning the element without data and event handlers, and replacing the existing elements. Not a very good solution, but the best I could come up with (if it works)!

Comment: hmmm, thank you. it seems that is still available for swiping.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 $("#zoom1").on('click', function() {
    if (state) {
```

try

```
$("#zoom1").one('click', function() {
    if (state) {
```